# C++ const reference to class variable within vector (or other dynamic container)

Tags: c++, vector, reference, constants, containers

pretty specific question here!

I have a class which holds data about a planet. For example, it has things like a vector (double x, double y, double z) to hold its position, and a double variable to hold its radius.

I often use references to get a "read only public access" to the private variables. I call a setter method to change the private variable.

However, I don't think this is allowed inside a dynamic container such as a vector or list.

I have tried "constant constant" pointers, with the idea being once initialized in an initialization list, they will not be able to point to anything else or modify the variable. But the same error message appears at compile time.

The message is this: "error: non-static const member `const double* const x`, can't use default assignment operator"

So, there is a problem with copying the class when I do a "push_back" on to a vector - right?

Here is an example code:

```
class planet{

    private:

        double _radius;

    public:

        // Constructor
        planet() : rad(_radius){
           _radius = 0.0f;
        }

        // This is a setter method - works fine
        void setrad(double new_rad){
            _radius = rad;
        }

        // This is a better solution to the getter method
        // - does not seem to work with dynamic containers!
        const double& rad; // This is initialized in the constructor list
};

int main(...){

...

    std::vector<planet> the_planets;
    planet next_planet_to_push;
    next_planet_to_push.setrad(1.0f);

    // This causes the error!
    the_planets.push_back(next_planet_to_add);

...

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with giving read only access via getter methods? I see no reason to store references here.

Comment: You need to define a copy-constructor & assignment operator for your Planet class. Try planet a; planet b; a = b;

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel that a reference is "better" than an access function, but it increases the object size and the runtime cost of access, and (as you've found) prevents the class from being trivially copyable. An access function should be inlined, in which case there should be no overhead compared with direct access to the member.

Comment: Ah yes I have just researched inline functions, this could be a good solution, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide your own copy constructor and assignment operator for classes that contain member references or `const` members (in your case, both).

The compiler-generated ones will attempt to do a shallow copy which is not possible in this case.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction on how to do this please?

Comment: @EdwardBird sure. Google copy constructor & assignment operator.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c9585/Copy-Constructors-and-Assignment-Operators.htm

Here is a good explanation which I have found for anyone in the future who has the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` requires `operator=` in order to work. Default `operator=` just assigns each member. It can't be done for `const &`

Comment: Can you point me in the direction on how to do this? What should I google for? Thanks!

Comment: @EdwardBird: i would do the same thing Kerrek SB recommends - use a simple getter

Comment: @EdwardBird: there is an option to use pointer instead of a references because a pointer can be rebind. But it's ugly. Don't do you it - use a simple getter

Comment: I tried a:
const double* const rad;
and then tried initializing it in an initialization list with my own basic constructor. Same error message! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EdwardBird: you can't change a const pointer. You can change a pointer to const. But please, don't do that. Provide a getter

Comment: Yes of course, it would be silly... That pointer could point ANYWHERE! I think I can use my own defined copy and assignment operators to make it work though... Is that possible?

Comment: @EdwardBird: I don't see a way to do so because you will need to rebind the reference

Comment: Yes, but I can use const double& rad without binding it until the constructor is called. There must surely be a way of getting it to work with my own copy and assignment operators to be used when one instance of the class is "pushed_back" onto the stack? Or perhaps there just is not any way of doing that? :(

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, elements of a `std::vector` must be assignable, so they can't contain const or reference members.

But why not have a simple accessor *function*:

```
double rad() const { return _radius; }
```

Comment: The answer is simple, the above solution is long to type, and it is much more intuitive to be able to type if(planet.x > 10) <do something> ... although I agree it is not good to be able to write to the variable in this way

Comment: Two extra parentheses are too long to type? Well, you could have an `std::reference_wrapper` member if you must.

Comment: No, not too long, just not intuitive! :) I will google std::reference_wrapper now.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Which one is more intuitive: the steering wheel of a car, or the rudder of a boat?

Comment: Come on, you cannot deny that using my.height is more intuitive than my.height()?! Who wants to call a method? Why not just grab the (readonly) variable!

But since you ask the question, the steering wheel is more intuitive. ;)

Comment: @EdwardBird I deny it: `my.height` is not more intuitive than `my.height()`. There.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Especially since we already have `myStr.length()`, `myGadget.size()` and `myEncoding.width()`! :-)

Comment: mm I see your point... might just use an inline getter... it seems to be the easiest solution...

Answer (score 0):

What is even the problem with just making the radius public?

If all the setter does is `this->radius = some_other_radius`, the code provides no benefit: is adding code that provides features that the language already provides worth it?

Comment: I don't like to have public variables, but I might just have to in this situation... :(

Comment: @EdwardBird if you want read only public access then this is definitely not the solution. An const accessor is easy enough.

Comment: @juanchopanza the existence of `setrad` reveals that public write access is also desired.